# Why is BSTR length prefix 4 bytes on 64-bit platforms?

Tags: c, winapi, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, bstr

It seems that on 64-bit platforms it would be reasonable to have a 8-byte length prefix. If we can address more than 4Gb of mem why not allow, say, 5Gb strings? Is the answer just "by specification" or there is some interoperability/backwards compatibility reasons that I'm not aware of?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `BSTR` data type is the standard COM string data type. Changing the length prefix would make it impossible to safely move strings between processes of different bitness (or at least make it significantly more complex). Since COM is the only relevant cross-bitness interop infrastructure it is necessary to have `BSTR`s behave the same way for 32-bit processes and 64-bit processes.

It is a tradeoff, imposing a 'limit' of 2GB in exchange for hassle-free marshaling of strings between processes of different bitness.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize you could pass BSTRs between 32bit and 64bit processes.

Comment: How would a BSTR pass from 32 to 64 bit process without reallocation?

Comment: @David Reallocation or not, the layout of a `BSTR` is documented. Custom and system-provided marshallers alike rely on this documented layout: a pointer to a data string with a 4-byte length prefix immediately preceding that data in memory. Consider an optimized marshaller for an object that keeps its state in shared memory. If that memory is mapped into both processes, you cannot have `BSTR`s with different memory layout for different bitnesses.

Answer (score 6):

One good reason is for compatibility with platform APIs like `MultiByteToWideChar` which accepts `int` lengths. There are many more string APIs that work with 32 bit lengths.

It's not actually a real limitation because I cannot conceive of a scenario where a `BSTR` of length >2GB would be the best solution to a problem.

Answer (score 1):

[BSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr) is a [length-prefixed string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Length-prefixed), so the first property is *length*, not address. Therefore it need not be the same size as the pointer and can just be the size that's enough for the application

For all practical purposes, 4GB is more than enough for a string, and keeping the maximum string size the same allows you to pass strings between processes without problem. For example if the length is a 64-bit type on 64-bit Windows then what will happen when you pass an 8GB string from a 64-bit process to a 32-bit process? Should the string be truncated or should an error be reported? The same prefix size may also improve backward compatibility

Comment: I have edited the question. What I'm asking is why not have a size_t instead of a 4-byte int.

Answer (score 0):

The most important reason is probably so that BSTR can continue to travel in `VARIANT`.  You will notice from the definition of `tagVARIANT` in oaidl.h that the `bstrVal` member appears to be part of the union of other types, but where is its length stored?  The answer is in the `wReserved2`/`wReserved3` members of the `VARIANT` structure that immediately precede the `bstrVal` member in memory.  There are 3 reserved words there so in theory BSTR's length could be expanded to 6 bytes, but if it got any bigger it would overwrite the `VARTYPE` member and VARIANT would no longer work. So `BSTR` is length-limited even on 64-bit platforms so that it can continue to travel in `VARIANT`.

Answer (score 0):

The range of applications where it's useful to have a large number of objects whose total size exceeds 2GiB is much greater than the range of applications where it's useful to either have any individual objects exceed 2GiB.  Even if individual operations on 64-bit values are no more expensive than operations on 32-bit values, the number of 32-bit values that will fit in each level of cache will be twice the number of 64-bit values likewise.  Thus, absent a good reason to use 64-bit values to hold object sizes, having a platform limit *individual* objects to 2GiB is a perfectly reasonable design decision, especially since code which isn't *designed* to work with larger objects will often malfunction in ways that would be prone to creating security vulnerabilities if run on systems that don't reject attempts to create objects greater than 2GiB.