# Does this test prove that malloc, calloc, new manage their own memory pool on my system?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, memory-management

I was writing a test program to see how BSTR works compared to a LPWSTR created using `malloc`.

I decided to call HeapSize on BSTR and LPWSTR to see whether they were on  the process heap or not.

The BSTR was not on the process heap, but I found that the LPWSTR had a HeapSize far larger than the Hello World string I copied into it. The value was very large and `GetLastError` returned 0 indicating no error. It seemed to give the same large for each LPWSTR i created with `malloc` so I made a test to see if it was just allocated from the same c runtime heap.

Here is the code for the above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Windowsx.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *testalloc1;
    void *testalloc2;
    LPWSTR w;
    BSTR b;

    testalloc1 = malloc(1024);
    testalloc2 = calloc(512, 2);
    w = (LPWSTR)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeof(L"Hello, World!"));
    wcsncpy(w, L"Hello, World!", sizeof(L"Hello, World!") / sizeof(WCHAR));
    b = SysAllocString(w);

    _putws(w);
    printf("%d.\n", *(DWORD *)(((LONG_PTR)b) - 4));
    _putws(b);

    printf("w -> %d.\n", HeapSize(GetProcessHeap(), 0, w));
    printf("GetLastError -> 0x%d.\n", GetLastError());
    printf("testalloc1 -> %d.\n", HeapSize(GetProcessHeap(), 0, testalloc1));
    printf("GetLastError -> 0x%d.\n", GetLastError());
    printf("testalloc2 -> %d.\n", HeapSize(GetProcessHeap(), 0, testalloc2));
    printf("GetLastError -> 0x%d.\n", GetLastError());
    printf("b -> %d.\n", HeapSize(
        GetProcessHeap(), 
        0, 
        (LPVOID)((LONG_PTR)b - sizeof(LONG_PTR))
    ));
    printf("GetLastError -> 0x%d.\n", GetLastError());

    return 0;
}
```

resulting in:

```
Hello, World!
26.
Hello, World!
w -> 28.
GetLastError -> 0x0.
testalloc1 -> 47120.
GetLastError -> 0x0.
testalloc2 -> 47120.
GetLastError -> 0x0.
b -> 32.
GetLastError -> 0x0.
```

I wrote another test to try understanding what's happening; I allocated multiple memory blocks using different heap-like allocation functions(HeapAlloc, malloc, calloc) and got this output:

```
malloc(1024) -> 215432.
calloc(512, 2) -> 215432
calloc(2, 512) -> 215432
new BYTE[1024] -> 215432
new BYTE[large] -> 1024.
malloc(large) -> 1024.
HeapAlloc(1024) -> 1024.
```

This is the code for the output above:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HANDLE heap;
    void *mem[7];
    LONG_PTR limit;

    heap = GetProcessHeap();    

    mem[0] = malloc(1024);
    mem[1] = calloc(512, 2);
    mem[2] = calloc(2, 512);
    mem[3] = (void *)new BYTE[1024];

    limit = HeapSize(heap, 0, mem[0]);

    mem[4] = (void *)new BYTE[limit];
    mem[5] = malloc(limit);
    mem[6] = HeapAlloc(heap, 0, 1024);

    printf("malloc(1024) -> %d.\n", HeapSize(heap, 0, mem[0]));
    printf("calloc(512, 2) -> %d.\n", HeapSize(heap, 0, mem[1]));
    printf("calloc(2, 512) -> %d.\n", HeapSize(heap, 0, mem[2]));    
    printf("new BYTE[1024] -> %d.\n", HeapSize(heap, 0, mem[3]));
    printf("new BYTE[large] -> %d.\n", HeapSize(heap, 0, mem[4]));
    printf("malloc(large) -> %d.\n", HeapSize(heap, 0, mem[5]));
    printf("HeapAlloc(1024) -> %d.\n", HeapSize(heap, 0, mem[6]));

    return 0;
}
```

Does this code reasonably prove that malloc, calloc, new all use memory pools as first choice for allocation, and HeapAlloc otherwise(on my system), or am I missing something?

Comment: Any memory allocation scheme that didn't use a pool would be broken.

Comment: you mean needlessly slow, right?

Comment: HeapSize behavior is [undefined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366706(v=vs.85).aspx) if you pass something that was not return by a previous call to HeapAlloc. It's possible that malloc etc allocate memory from the heap, but do not return the pointer directly. They might return an interior pointer. (Indeed, `new[]` frequently returns an interior pointer. And `BSTR` is in fact required to return an interior pointer due to the placement of the string size ahead of the first character.)

Comment: i am asking on this particular system. It can't be undefined if it predictably returns the same value as that returned by blocks created with new. They must be allocated using the global heap, otherwise HeapSize would not succeed. If HeapSize failed, it would indicate it wasn't created using the specified heap(obtained from GetProcessHeap).

Comment: It doesn't fail. 'If the `lpMem` parameter refers to a heap allocation that is not in the heap specified by the `hHeap` parameter, the behavior of the `HeapSize` function is *undefined.*' Emphasis added.

Comment: Wait... that's the legendary Reymond Chen O.o. Anyway, Ill post the sample I referred to at beginning of my post. The BSTR created from SysCreateString passed to HeapSize returned 0, so it wasn't using the process heap, doesn't that make it external?

Comment: Oh by interior pointer, you mean that it's a pointer inside an allocated region(eg it's shifted by 4 bytes of the actual allocation). I thought you meant internal as in in GetProcessHeap, and external if elsewhere.

Comment: Note that it isn't a question of what the behaviour is "on your system", malloc, calloc and new are all part of the C runtime, so it depends on which compiler you're using.  Also, typically, on whether you've built in debug or release mode.  You may well have access to the source code, in which case there's no need to guess.

Comment: you're right, if I understand correctly, malloc, calloc, new are all part of the C runtime which can vary in implementation between visual studio's default, and mingw's default, among others, whereas HeapAlloc is the system dependant part.  That said, I was asking whether given the observation, it is safe to assume that the C standard library I link to is using a pool, or if I am missing something. I was having doubts whether it's a safe conclusion or not.

Comment: sizeof(L"Hello, World!") is the size of a pointer so you have buffer overrun. That said, your question seems pointless.

Comment: no, string literals are always counted as byte arrays. test it yourself. sizeof a string literal or a array will give a correct length, including the null terminator. try a simple program: `int main(int argc, char **argv){return sizeof(L"Hi");}` it will return 6.

Comment: `wcsncpy(w, L"Hello, World!", sizeof(L"Hello, World!"));` is serious error and buffer overflow. must be `wcsncpy(w, L"Hello, World!", sizeof(L"Hello, World!")/sizeof(WCHAR));`

Comment: Fair enough. I've  still no idea what your problem is. What even is your question?

Comment: My bad, I assumed that the length argument of wcsncpy was byte based. Fortunately wcsncpy stops at null terminator, so it should still work, but yeah that was an erroneous assumption, I'll fix the code.

Comment: also call `HeapSize` for `SysAllocString` is error and must be break under debugger because pointer returned by `SysAllocString` not at begin of allocated memory block

Comment: @RbMm I am not sure what you mean. It is at beginning of the allocated block, w is the same pointer i got from HeapAlloc, which is  the beginning of the allocated block.

Comment: `Fortunately wcsncpy stops at null terminator,` - no it not stop and was buffer overflow. *If count is greater than the length of strSource, the destination string is padded with null characters up to length count*

Comment: @Dmitry - the `SysAllocString` return not pointer to allocated block - and if call `HeapSize` with this pointer - will be exception if process debugged

Comment: @RbMm that's embarassing, that's actually horrible, I tested it and it actually pads with zeroes. Thanks for letting me know. Oh, I see what you're saying; that's a part of what I was checking, what would happen if I gave a pointer to this block to HeapSize, to me it returned 0, but I did it in mingw so it didn't crash, I assumed this is because the pointer is not contained in the process heap.

Comment: Why are you intentionally passing invalid values to HeapSize? Do you have an actual problem?

Comment: @David Heffernan in my original test, I was curious how SysAllocString behaved(whether it was allocated on the process heap or elsewhere) so I decided to try out HeapSize which seemed to answer that question. In this question I'm asking whether this is a reasonable way to check whether the current system runtime is allocating memory from a pool on the process heap, or somewhere else, as I was having doubts.

Comment: The only thing you can pass to HeapSize is something allocated by HeapAlloc and friends. Surely the documentation says so. Why are you persisting?

Comment: I'm not persisting, I only called it once on each friend, and it failed on the pointer returned by SysAllocString, which told me it wasn't on the process heap.

Comment: It's likely that calls to `malloc` will use the process heap, but won't return you the base pointer returned by the internal call to `HeapAlloc`. Instead they store meta data there, and return you a pointer at an offset. Basically, your code proves nothing at all.

Comment: I wasnt trying to prove anything about sysallocstring(it's too naive), I'm trying to prove for the new, malloc, calloc, and whether they use internal pool or use HeapAlloc directly, or perhaps not use Heap at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for call [`HeapSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366706(v=vs.85).aspx) for some memory pointer we must at first know the handle to the heap in which the memory block resides, and at second we must be sure that this memory pointer was exactly at begin of allocated block - otherwise `HeapSize` generate exception, if we under debugger, and not return correct value.

but however possible by given pointer determinate - are it belong to some heap (in process can be several heaps) and not only block size, but offset from block begin (say `SysAllocString` return not pointer to allocated block, but with offset 8 from block begin). this can be done with help of [`GetProcessHeaps`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366571(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`HeapWalk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366710(v=vs.85).aspx) (inside [HeapLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366702(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`HeapUnlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366707(v=vs.85).aspx))

```
void TestHeapPointer(PVOID pv)
{
    static volatile UCHAR guz;

    ULONG NumberOfHeaps = 0, n = 8;

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PHANDLE ProcessHeaps;
    };

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    BOOL bFound = FALSE;

    do 
    {
        NumberOfHeaps = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca((n - NumberOfHeaps) * sizeof(HANDLE)), stack) / sizeof(HANDLE);

        if (NumberOfHeaps >= (n = GetProcessHeaps(NumberOfHeaps, ProcessHeaps)))
        {
            do 
            {
                HANDLE hHeap = *ProcessHeaps++;

                if (HeapLock(hHeap))
                {
                    PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY phe = {};

                    while (HeapWalk(hHeap, &phe))
                    {
                        if (phe.wFlags & PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY_BUSY)
                        {
                            ULONG_PTR ofs = (ULONG_PTR)pv - (ULONG_PTR)phe.lpData;
                            if (ofs < phe.cbData)
                            {
                                DbgPrint("%p in %p block %x size ofs=%x\n", pv, phe.lpData, phe.cbData, ofs);
                                bFound = TRUE;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    HeapUnlock(hHeap);
                }

            } while (!bFound && --NumberOfHeaps);

            break;
        }
    } while (NumberOfHeaps < n);

    if (!bFound) DbgPrint("%p not in heaps", pv);
}
```

and test like

```
static const WCHAR cstr[] =  L"Hello, World!";

if (PVOID pv = malloc(sizeof(cstr)))
{
    TestHeapPointer(pv);
    free(pv);
}

if (BSTR b = SysAllocString(cstr))
{
    TestHeapPointer(b);
    SysFreeString(b);
}
```

Comment: oh! since SysAllocString returns an internal pointer, HeapSize gets confused because it's not at the start of the block. My question wasn't concerning this(that was a side test), but im curious if it will work on the pointer - sizeof(LONG_PTR). And it does!

Comment: I modified my original code so it doesn't have the naive misuse of HeapSize(since that test proved nothing; I didn't realize that internal pointers also fail with HeapSize). Anyway, Ill accept the answer since i think all points were answered in the comment section or here.

Comment: @Dmitry - this is already internal implementation of SysAllocString - how many bytes he reserved (for string len) before string data `(LPVOID)((LONG_PTR)b - sizeof(LONG_PTR)` - now yes, faster `sizeof (SIZE_T)` which is 4 or 8

Comment: @RbMm: Independent of system bitness, the [size prefix of a `BSTR` is *always* 4 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23098728/1889329). This is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069.aspx) as well.

Comment: @IInspectable - try test it yoursel on x64 system. i got exactly 8 byte. how minimum i test on win 10 x64

Comment: @IInspectable - on win7 x64 - also prefix is 8 byte len. think this is `sizeof(SIZE_T)` exactly. anyway this is internal implementation

Comment: I just did. The size prefix is 4 bytes, running 64-bit code on 64-bit Windows 10.0.15063, compiled with Visual Studio 2017 15.3.3. It *may* be possible for the size prefix to get additional padding towards lower addresses, to satisfy alignment constraints, but that padding isn't part of the size prefix, and would be an implementation detail.

Comment: @IInspectable - how you test this ? all my test and looking dissasembly for `SysAllocString` show 8 bytes prefix (from allocated block) exactly

Comment: @IInspectable - for test you can use and my code which i paste here. or simplest test `HeapSize(GetProcessHeap(),0, (PBYTE)b - 8);` - return to you correct value when `HeapSize(GetProcessHeap(),0, (PBYTE)b - 4);` break under debugger. and asm code - https://prnt.sc/ghrgw5

Comment: I'm not arguing, that the system wouldn't allocate more memory than the 4-byte size prefix. The 4-byte size prefix, however, is not an implementation detail. It's part of the published contract of the `BSTR` type.

Comment: @IInspectable - ok, understand what you mean. yes. the 4 bytes prefix used before string data. but i all time say and mean about offset pointer returned by `SysAllocString` string from allocated memory block begin.